# removing one class but not both

Tags: jquery

I current have this code that shows/hides content based on a select option.

How can i work into add and remove a class based on whatever the option is selected but without removing the .desarea?

```
<option value="country1">
<option valye="country2">

<div class="desarea country1">

//Create destination switch
    $('#regionselect').change(function(){
        var selected = $(this).find(':selected');
        $('.regionDetail').fadeOut();
        var count = $('.countrylist').length;
        $('.countrylist').slideUp(function(){
            if(!--count) {
               $('.'+selected.val()).slideDown();
            }       
        });
    });
```

Comment: Using `addClass` and `removeClass`: http://api.jquery.com/addClass/ , http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/

Comment: but how do i work in the selected value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want ?

```
$('#regionselect').change(function(){
    var selectedValue = $(this).val();

    $('div').removeClass(selectedValue);
});
```

**EDIT**
So is this better ? http://jsfiddle.net/pmEVU/2/

```
$('#regionselect').change(function(){
    var selectedValue = $(this).val();

    $('option', this).each(function() {
        var currentValue = $(this).val();

        if (currentValue == selectedValue)
            $('div').addClass(selectedValue);
        else
            $('div').removeClass(currentValue);
    });
});
```

Comment: The class will be added to .desarea and then removed when another item is selected... so for example (.desarea country1) where country1 is the previous value selected.  This will be removed and replaced with whatever the next value is

Comment: @Andy Is the new solution better ?

Comment: I/ve added it but its adding all the option values, not just the one i selected?

Comment: @Andy Ooops yes, I tested with 2 classes and one initialized.
I have edited my answer with a new solution ;)

Answer (score 2):

Use [`jQuery.addClass`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) and [`jQuery.removeClass`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) to add and remove class names from an element without affecting other classes the element may have.

Comment: But how can i remove the old class?  what do i use to find it?

Comment: If you have the class you want to remove, use it to find the element: `$('.class-to-remove').removeClass('class-to-remove')`

Answer (score 1):

The `removeClass` function will remove any named class from the set of matched elements, for example `$('#selector').removeClass('oldClass');`.

Conversely, the `addClass` function will add a new class to the elements matched by the selector.